# Ability to link API report back to site

Tags: openfda

I currently do not see a way to link a result returned from openFDA API to the sites report. For example the recall below does not have a link back to the report on the fda site. Is there a way to look up a recall using the `recall_number`? I also do not get any results back plugging in the recall number here https://www.fda.gov/safety/recalls-market-withdrawals-safety-alerts

```
    {
        "status": "Ongoing",
        "city": "Baltimore",
        "state": "MD",
        "country": "United States",
        "classification": "Class I",
        "openfda": {},
        "product_type": "Food",
        "event_id": "91653",
        "recalling_firm": "FRESH IDEATION FOOD GROUP, LLC dba Fresh Creative Cuisine",
        "address_1": "2800 Wegworth Ln",
        "address_2": "",
        "postal_code": "21230-3300",
        "voluntary_mandated": "Voluntary: Firm initiated",
        "initial_firm_notification": "Press Release",
        "distribution_pattern": "The recalled product was distributed to the following states: MD, PA, DE, NY, DC, NJ, NC, CT, SC, VA, MA .",
        "recall_number": "F-0482-2023",
        "product_description": "Bistro To Go, Gourmet Cheese & Fruit Plate, Net Wt. 6 Oz. Single Serving, Keep refrigerated",
        "product_quantity": "18 units",
        "reason_for_recall": "On 02/03/2023, FRESH IDEATION FOOD GROUP, LLC dba Fresh Creative Cuisine of Baltimore, MD is  initiating a recall of  various products sold from January 24, 2023 through January 30, 2023 because the products have the potential to be contaminated with Listeria monocytogenes .",
        "recall_initiation_date": "20230203",
        "center_classification_date": "20230310",
        "report_date": "20230322",
        "code_info": "UPC Code : 813141021144"
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm Violet Wren with the openFDA team. The FDA dataset you linked to does not appear to store recall numbers. As such, searching with them will unfortunately yield no results. Your best bet for cross-referencing from our datasets to this one would be to look by product name or date, but note that these are *not* the same dataset, so you may not find results for every piece of data in our datasets.

I hope that helps,

Violet Wren,

openFDA Tech Lead

Edit:

Just in case this is what you're looking for, our data does translate in the way you're trying with the FDA's Recall Report site, which you can find here:

https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/ires/index.cfm#tabNav_advancedSearch

You can search recall numbers there like this: `"recall_number": "F-0482-2023"`.